# Context-free grammar to recognize end-of-line whitespace

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar

I am trying to write a context-free grammar to do something very simple—to parse a string into a list of alternating sections of (1) end-of-line whitespace and (2) everything else. For example:

```
This.first.line...\n..and.this....second.line\n.\n..and.final.line
```

(showing `" "` as `"."` and newlines as `"\n"`for readability) is parsed as

```
"This.first.line", "...\n..", "and.this....second.line", "\n.\n..", "and.final.line"
```

I wrote this grammar:

```
string = raw_start | newline_start
raw_start = raw_section [newline_start]
newline_start = newline_section [raw_start]
raw_section = {any_character_except_newline}
newline_section = {whitespace_except_newline} new_line {any_whitespace_character}
```

But this is not correct because the `{any_character_except_newline}` will consume the spaces leading up to newlines, when I want those included with the `new_line_section`.

Is it possible to say "Consume spaces, unless they are right before a newline" without losing the context-free property of the grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, context-free is not a problem. Both "end-of-line whitespace" and "everything else" are regular languages.

For reference, here are the regular expressions (formally regular, not "recognizable with some 'regex' package"). We suppose that **`A`** is the alphabet, and define:

```
NOTSPACE = { ∀x | x ∈ A ∧ x ≠ NL ∧ x ≠ SPACE }
NOTEOL   = { ∀x | x ∈ A ∧ x ≠ NL }
EVERYTHING_ELSE = { xωy | x,y ∈ NOTSPACE ∧ ω ∈ NOTEOL* } ⋃ NOTSPACE
EOL_WHITESPACE = { ωNLγ | ω,γ ∈ {SPACE, NL}* }
```

That can easily be transformed into a CFG. (It's possible that the text ends with whitespace which doesn't include a newline. The following ignores that possibility, but it could easily be added):

```
S → Spaces
S → S Other
S → S EOL_WS
Spaces → ε
Spaces → Spaces [ ]
Other → [^ \n] Line [^ \n]
Other → [^ \n]
Line → ε
Line → Line [^\n]
EOL_WS → Spaces NL_Spaces
NL_Spaces → NL_Space
NL_Spaces → NL_Spaces NL_Space
NL_Space → [/n] Spaces
```

As written, the above is ambiguous because it does not insist that `Other` and `EOL_WS` be maximally long. That's easy to fix but tedious, and since the OP only asks for a CFG and not an unambiguous or LR(1) CFG, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: For me, the key to understanding was the line `EVERYTHING_ELSE = { xωy | x,y ∈ NOTSPACE ∧ ω ∈ NOTEOL* }`, and recognizing that I had to require that the last character in a `raw_section` be a non-whitespace character.

Comment: @drhagen: Cool. Fixed the error in the definition of `EOL_WHITESPACE`. In fact, in that rule, ω could be simply `SPACE*`, but unless you care about ambiguity, it makes no difference. Also fixed the bug in `Other` (I didn't leave the possibility of it being just a single non-whitespace character.) All of which demonstrates the importance of actually testing grammars, which I still haven't done in this case :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a translation of rici's great answer into the EBNF format I used in my question:

```
string = raw_start | newline_start
raw_start = raw_section [newline_start]
newline_start = newline_section [raw_start]
raw_section = any_nonwhite_character [{any_character_except_newline} any_nonwhite_character]
newline_section = {whitespace_except_newline} new_line {any_whitespace_character}
```

The key was changing the definition of `raw_section` to require that it end with a nonwhite character. This simple grammar will not match empty strings or strings that end with a space, but that is easy to fix.